# How much is the permeability of this attached inductor core?

Tags: inductor, passive-filter, vfd

I want to use this inductor for AC line filter as line reactor. Its inductance value is 6 mH but I don't know the exact value of permeability of the material. It will be used with VFD at the input to remove the harmonics. The input current will be from 2 to 7 A.

Could you please tell me the exact value of the permeability of this material?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a datasheet from the manufacterer? Anything else is a guess.

Comment: No, I don't have a datasheet. I bought it from scratch.

Comment: Use the advice by Andy below to get the Al, but how do you know you are not saturating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some geometrical inputs (internal and external radii, height):
[image]

Be careful: permeability depends on the magnetic field, which depends on current.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has 36 turns and because inductance is proportional to turns squared we can say that the inductance for 1 turn will be: -

4.63 uH because 4.63 uH x \$36^2\$ = 6 mH.

The inductor's \$A_L\$ is the inductance of 1 turn i.e. \$A_L\$ = 4.63 uH/turn.

And, the permeability of the core is related to \$A_L\$ like so: -

$$\mu_e =\dfrac{A_L\cdot \ell_e}{ A_e} $$

Where le is the mean length of the core and Ae is the cross sectional area.

An example: if the mean length of the core is 5 cm and the cross sectional area is 1 cm\$^2\$, the absolute permeability will be 4.63 x 10\$^{-6}\$ x 0.05 / 0.01\$^2\$ = 0.002315 or, in relative terms, divide by the permeability of free space (\$4\pi\cdot 10^{-7}\$) to get a value of about 1842.

Get your measurement stick out!